# Vector Translation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have two three component vectors, lets call them $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

I want to find $\vec z$ such that $\|\vec z\| = \|\vec x\|$ and the $x$ and $y$-orientation of $\vec z$ equals the x and y-orientation of $\vec y$.

**EDIT:** And the z-component contribution in $\vec x$ is matched in $\vec z$.

Basically I want to find the vector for an object that's falling just as fast who's heading is different. Is this possible?

Comment: By *"x and y-orientation of $\vec z$ equals the x and y-orientation of $\vec y$"* you mean that that $\vec z$ points in the same direction as $\vec y$? Then it should be $\frac{||x||}{||y||}\vec y$...maybe $\pm$ if you allow the oposite direction as well...

Comment: @draks... Yes I do mean that $\vec z$ will point in the same direction as $\vec y$ within the xy-plane, but I don't understand your equation.

Comment: I normalize $\vec y$ by dividing it by its norm $||\vec y||$ and then a scale it to the desired length by multiplying it with $||\vec x||$...

Comment: oh I forgot the third dimension, let me think...[thinking]...I thought and it it should look like this$\frac{||\vec x||}{\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+a^2}}\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\a}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec y=\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\y_3}$, then it should look like this: 
$$
\vec z=\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2+a^2}}\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\a};
$$
it has $x$ and $y$ components of $\vec y$ and the length of $||\vec x||$. Now choose
$$
a\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2+a^2}}=x_3
$$
and solve it for $a$...

Comment: I'm unclear what $a$ is, is $a = x_3$? Nope, that doesn't make sense cause $x_3$ is not scaled to match $y$...

Comment: @JonathanMee $a$ is a free parameter...

Comment: What I think I'm getting is that: $$z_1 = \frac{||\vec x||}{\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+a^2}}y_1$$ and: $$z_2 = \frac{||\vec x||}{\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+a^2}}y_2$$ and: $$z_3 = x_3$$ but I still can'y use that to find $\vec z$ cause I don't know what $a$ is.

Comment: @JonathanMee any vector of the above form has the length you asked for and it points along $x$ and $y$ as you requested; irrespective of $z_3$, which I called $a$. I changed that if this was too confusing...

Comment: So I've posted an answer below, it seems like I just need to scale the xy-components of $\vec y$ and then stomp the z-component. Which seems like it should give identical results to you're equation, but the two are certainly not mathematically equal. I think it's because your messes up the proportions. For example if I have $\vec x = 1\mathbf i + 1\mathbf j + 2\mathbf k$ and $\vec y = 10\mathbf i + 10\mathbf j + 13\mathbf k$ your equation will significantly decrease the z contribution of the resulting vector.

Comment: @JonathanMee "the z contribution of the resulting vector" is a free parameter $z_3$ and you can chose it as large as you like it...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find this vector by scaling the z-component of $\vec x$ and then just using it directly in $\vec y$'s z-component to form $\vec z$.

The modifier you'll want to use is $x_3$ scaled by the xy-size of $\vec x$ over the xy-size of $\vec y$: $$z_3 = x_3\sqrt{\frac{y_1^2 + y_2^2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}$$

Then just set $z_1 = y_1$ and $z_2 = y_2$ and you have your vector!

To scale $\vec z$ such that $\|\vec z\| = \|\vec x\|$ simply set $\vec z$ to $\hat z\|\vec x\|$.

Comment: Why to fix the $z$ component with the value of $x_3$? That's not necessary, it's just one example. Set $z_3=x_3$ in my answer to recover yours as a special case...

Comment: @draks... That's just the thing. I don't know how large to choose it in your code. I need a ratio between the xy-components of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ to know *how* to choose how large it is. In the example I gave in the comments of your question your equation will give: $4.7\mathbf i + 4.7\mathbf j + 0.8\mathbf k$ if you just directly plug in $x_3$. My answer will give: $.1\mathbf i + .1\mathbf j + 2\mathbf k$... Stink, neither equation works. I need to refactor...

Comment: See, I normalize any of my vectors (irrespective of $z_3$) to unit length of $1$ (by division with the norm) and then I multiply by $||\vec x||$...

Comment: @draks... Looking at my original question I see how I didn't clearly specify what I wanted. I've edited. If you can tell me how to do that in your equation I'm ready, I just currently don't see how.

Comment: Done; have a look...

Comment: @draks... Still doesn't work T.T I get $4.1\mathbf i + 4.1\mathbf j + .8\mathbf k$ which doesn't have the same rate of fall as $\vec x$. In my example where $\vec x = 1\mathbf i + 1\mathbf j + 2\mathbf k$ and $\vec y = 10\mathbf i + 10\mathbf j + 13\mathbf k$, because $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ point the same direction I should get $\vec z = \vec x$.

Comment: No they don't point in the same 3-dimensional direction. Only their projections in the $xy$ plane  (looking down the $z$ axis)  point in the same...and I get different values for your example ($\vec z= 1.714\mathbf i + 1.714\mathbf j + 0.342\mathbf k$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24985/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-draks).